# Changing the default directory of website

Tags: lamp, apache2.4

So I have my website right now in `/var/www/html` and I would want it to be in `/var/www/html/website` but I don't want to add to my website link the name of the folder so I would want when I go on my website go straight to the index file in website folder and not do `website.com/website` to get there if that makes sense.

So later on I will be able to add another folder `website2` to create a subdomain with a `website2` folder and then so I could get there by `website2.website.com`

Comment: Just to make sure. You want to change the default directory from `/var/www/html` to `/var/www/html/website` right?

Answer (score 1):

The following steps change the default directory (apache)

1. `sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf`
2. edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf` such that DocumentRoot points to `/var/www/html/website`
3. edit `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` such that `Directory /var/www` is changed to `Directory /var/www/html/website`
4. `sudo a2dissite 000-default && sudo a2ensite mysite`
5. `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Now when you place your index file in `/var/www/html/website` it is displayed when you open your site (http://127.0.0.1)

For full documentation look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)